# Solve in positive integers: $5^x 7^y +4=3^z$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Solve in positive integers: $5^x 7^y +4=3^z$.

I tried to solve it with log but I couldn't complete.

Comment: Sorry about the false start with the first version of my answer. I've repaired it and (hopefully) also made it even simpler.

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if there are any parts that don't make sense, and I'll be happy to elaborate!

Answer (score 4):

Rewrite this as

> $$3^z-4=5^x7^y$$

Then we see, because $x>0$, that

$$3^z-4\equiv 0\mod 5 \iff 3^z\equiv -1\mod 5$$

so $z=2j$ is even.

Then we have $(3^j-2)(3^j+2)=5^x7^y$. Since the gcd of these two divides $4$--because $(3^j-2)+(3^j+2)=4$--we have that they are coprime (any larger factor would then be a factor of $5^x7^y$ which is odd), i.e. one of the following two cases hold

> $$\begin{cases} 3^j+2=5^x\quad ,\quad 3^j-2=7^y \\ 3^j+2=7^y\quad ,\quad3^j-2=5^x\end{cases}.$$

In the second case we get $7^y\equiv 2\mod 3$ which is impossible, so we are in case $1$. Then $3^j=7^y+2$ so $j\equiv 2\mod 6$ which recovers our original conclusion, that $z=12\ell+4\equiv 0\mod 4$, which is a contradiction as this implies

> $$-3\equiv 3^z-4\equiv 5^x7^y\equiv 0\mod 5.$$

Comment: i found a solution for this, i will post my answer soon if it doesnt contain any mistakes

Comment: waiting for your solution

Comment: @AdamHughes i copied part of your answer, i hope this is ok for you

Comment: @supinf I fixed mine as well. It looks like my original conclusion still works out just for different reasons. Indeed it still doesn't require any higher things than prime moduli, and fits neatly together.

Comment: @majid there you go. It should be fixed totally.

Comment: @user26486 yep, thanks. Fixed!

Comment: @JimmyK4542 thanks again for the catch. Everything should be better now.

Answer (score 1):

[Based on the work from @Adam Hughes]

We assume $x>1$ and rewrite it:

$$3^z-4=5^x7^y \Rightarrow
3^z-4\equiv 0\mod 5 \iff 3^z\equiv -1\mod 5$$

so $z=2j$ is even.

Then we have $(3^j-2)(3^j+2)=5^x7^y$. Since the gcd of these two divides $4$--because $(3^j+2)-(3^j-2)=4$--we have that they are coprime (any larger factor would then be a factor of $5^x7^y$ which is odd), i.e. one of the following two cases hold

$$\begin{cases} 3^j+2=5^x\quad ,\quad 3^j-2=7^y \\ 3^j+2=7^y\quad ,\quad3^j-2=5^x\end{cases}.$$

**Case 2**:
$3^j+2=7^y\quad ,\quad3^j-2=5^x \Rightarrow 7^y = 4 + 5^x$, which is impossible if you look at it $\mod 3$.

So we have **Case 1**:
$3^j-2=7^y\quad ,\quad3^j+2=5^x \Rightarrow 7^y+4 = 5^x$. If you look at it $\mod 4$, you get $2|y$, so we write $y=2 y_2$

We look at it $\mod 25$: this gives us
$7^y + 4 \equiv 49^{y_2} +4 \equiv (-1)^{y_2} + 4 \equiv 5^x \equiv 0$, which is impossible.

it remains to look at x=1, here we have the only solution $y=0,x=1,z=2$ (you can ignore this if you only want strictly positive solutions)

Comment: ah thx, i will fix it :)

Comment: fixed, @user26486

Comment: Why does the main part of this look exactly like Adam Hughes' answer?

Comment: @robjohn this is because his answer had mistakes in the second part and i was able to fix these. after that, he found a solution for the second part too. see the comments under his answer

Comment: Perhaps, but a large part is copied word for word, using very similar format. There should be at least some mention that part of the answer is copied and from where.

Answer (score 0):

$5^x7^y+4=3^z$ with $x,y,z\in\Bbb Z^+$.

mod $5$ gives $z=2z_1,\, z_1\in\Bbb Z^+$. Then $5^x7^y=\left(3^{z_1}+2\right)\left(3^{z_1}-2\right)$.

$\gcd(3^{z_1}+2, 3^{z_1}-2)=1$, so two cases:

- $7^y=3^{z_1}+2$, impossible mod $3$.
- $5^x=3^{z_1}+2$. mod $3$: $x$ is odd. mod $8$: $z_1$ is odd.
  $7^y=3^{z_1}-2$. mod $7$: $z_1$ is even. Contradiction.